# blank screen appears when using remmina via vnc protocol

Tags: vnc, tightvnc

I have installed tightvncserver on a remote server and can run it. I use Remmina to access the server via vnc protocol and it works, my only problem is the desktop does not show. The screen that shows up is just blank[image]
Please reference the picture. Don't mind the background just the window shown.I have no idea why its showing like this